# ASP.NET Core routing to files in wwwroot

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app with a folder `images` under the folder `wwwroot` in the published web site.

I am having difficulty having consistency with setting the proper path for this `images` folder when trying to access it in the _Layout.cshtml.

I added StaticFiles middleware but it doesnt work in the specific case where i try to add a header a style with background:

```
<header class="main-header" role="banner" style="background: url(../MyImages/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0">
```

The static files configuration:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images")),
            RequestPath = "/MyImages"
        });
```

What am i missing here?
Bare in mind i am new to web development.

Thank you.

EDIT:
this:

```
<a href="~/" title="Home" rel="home">
        <img src="~/MyImages/logo.png" style="background-color:white;" alt="Home">
```

Works fine no matter what page im at.

Comment: In the log from your app you should be able to see the full path of the GET request coming in. From that it should be easy to see what you're missing.

Comment: It just shows me my current path + what im writing inside. for example if i put url(~/Images/bg-header.png) the path will be http://website/webalias/~/MyImages/bg-header.png

Comment: That means that the file should be under wwwroot/website/webalias/~/MyImages/bg-header.png. And that looks wrong.

Comment: check out my edit please

Comment: Are you intentionally using a relative path here: `url(../MyImages/bg-header.png)`? Try `url('/MyImages/bg-header.png')`.

Comment: That doesnt work. it dismisses my alias.. so the image is requested from localhost/MyImages and not from localhost/alias/images

Comment: What do you mean by 'alias'? I thought `/MyImages` was the alias.

Comment: I add the web site to the default web site in IIS, and i give it a name - thats what i mean by alias

Comment: Try using `background: url(@Url.Content("~/MyImages/bg-header.png") ...`.

Comment: not working, and now i dont even have an error in the chrome console..

Comment: @KirkLarkin this works thank you! i just forgot a closing parenthesis..